# PHP, Swift-mailer problem

Tags: php, swiftmailer

When I click submit button on my contact page, trying to submit a form that uses swift-mailer, I get this:

> Warning: fopen(uploads/)
>   [function.fopen]: failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/polycys2/public_html/html/swift-mailer/lib/classes/Swift/ByteStream/FileByteStream.php
>   on line 131

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_IoException' with message 'Unable to open file for reading [uploads/]' in /home/polycys2/public_html/html/swift-mailer/lib/classes/Swift/ByteStream/FileByteStream.php:133

Stack trace: 
#0 /home/polycys2/public_html/html/swift-mailer/lib/classes/Swift/ByteStream/FileByteStream.php(77): Swift_ByteStream_FileByteStream->_getReadHandle()
#1 /home/polycys2/public_html/html/swift-mailer/lib/classes/Swift/Mime/SimpleMimeEntity.php(660): Swift_ByteStream_FileByteStream->read(8192) 
#2 /home/polycys2/public_html/html/swift-mailer/lib/classes/Swift/Mime/SimpleMimeEntity.php(337): Swift_Mime_SimpleMimeEntity->_readStream(Object(Swift_ByteStream_FileByteStream)) 
#3 /home/polycys2/public_html/html/swift-mailer/lib/classes/Swift/Mime/SimpleMimeEntity.php(448): Swift_Mime_SimpleMimeEntity->getBody()
#4 /home/polycys2/public_html/html/swift-mailer/lib/classes/Swift/Mime/SimpleMimeEntity.php(463): Swift_Mime_SimpleMimeEntity->toString()
#5 /home/polycys2/public_html/html/swift-mailer/lib/classes/Swift/ in /home/polycys2/public_html/html/swift-mailer/lib/classes/Swift/ByteStream/FileByteStream.php on line 133
```

The full path exists on the server, although the error message says 'no such file or directory.
What could be the problem?
Thank you all in advance!
And merry Christmas!

Comment: `uploads/` will be relative to the current working directory. What is your working directory in that script? Try `getcwd()`.

Comment: So `uploads/` is a file?

Comment: @Pekka: Either way, opening a directory (e.g.: `fopen('/usr', 'r');` does not yield an error. However, it probably won't do much even if it exists.

Comment: @netcoder Swift seems to explicitly request a file (see the exception's error message)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to supply the full path to `uploads` not a realtive path because that is going to be interpreted as relative to class file that tries to open your attachment.

Try using `realpath` before passing the path to Swift.

> $path = realpath('uploads/');

Comment: I had a similar issue with Laravel, using SwiftMailer and Twig and the message.embed() function.  I didn't realize that the function was using the overall scripts context and working directory, as opposed to the Twig context and base dir.  I had to make the paths relative to overall context, i.e., laravel's public/ dir, instead of the Twig template context and base dir, which I was using without thinking.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your help!
The problem was my absentmindedness - I forgot to create 'upload' directory there.
Now it works fine.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

Controller.php

```
$mail = Yii::$app->mailer->compose('@app/mail/embed-mail',
[
     'term' => Url::to('@webroot/images/term.png'),
     'logo' => Url::to('@webroot/images/LOGO.jpg')
]
```

And embed-mail.php

```
<img src="<?= $message->embed($terminal); ?>"/>
<img src="<?= $message->embed($logo); ?>"/>
```

I hope this works for you

Answer (score 0):

From the error messages, it seems as if you were specifying a directory where a file path is needed. Maybe because of a missing variable that is supposed to contain the file name.