# Laravel mail Swift_IoException Unable to open file for reading

Tags: laravel, swiftmailer

Im trying to send attachment in email it give below error 
but when i check given url file is there and download work.

```
Swift_IoException in FileByteStream.php line 144:
Unable to open file for reading [http://sendemail.domain.com/attachment/warburg_brochure.pdf]
```

Comment: Check the permission of that directory, what is it? Check if its readable and it not, change the permission to 755 by typing the command: `chmod 755 <directory of the PDF files>

Comment: This question and its answers can really help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531180/php-swift-mailer-problem and also this: http://laravel.io/forum/05-05-2014-problem-sending-an-email-with-attachment

Comment: file its directory and parent directory have 755.  even file is downloading.

Comment: Check the link I just posted, those will solve your problem.

Comment: @d3r1ck tried that upload_max_filesize, etc did not work

Comment: Can you expatiate on the problem you are facing, add more information please so that other can help.

Comment: is there a way to load file in memory and use attachData

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same issue, check the mime type of file you are attaching. To debug more try different extension files.

Answer (score 0):

You might be giving a wrong path of attachments.
the following codes can work when using  sync
Mail::to($email)
                ->send();

```
$this->attach($path), [
            'mime' => 'application/pdf',
        ]);
```

But when using another queue driver like db
Mail::to($email)
                ->queue
you had to provide the full path like this

```
$this->attach(public_path($path)), [
        'mime' => 'application/pdf',
    ]);
```

That is how my issue got solved! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved using `uploading the image` which was not physically exist earlier!
You can try it. Check if all images,liked to the mail are physically exist in the folder.
There may be other issues. 
Try to give 777 permission to those images liked to mail template.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same problem and found solution by providing the absolute path of the file you want to attach. Use Laravel function `base_path()` to get absolute path of your project and mention relative path of your file.

```
Syntax: base_path('public/myFiles/filename.pdf');
```

Hope it will help...

Answer (score 0):

I also facing the same problem, after check log file, I found that swift getting file  from http:// not directly from filesystem.

In my case I install server behind firewall and use private ip, this make my server unable to access URL (https://newsletter.domain.com/media/images/aee0c6394d02225d1f740dc.jpeg) directly. The problem actually comes from network configuration.

Easy fix from me is edit hosts file add FQDN with it's private ip

> 192.168.0.2 newsletter.domain.com

Hope it will help...

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue a couple of times, most of the times the issue is regarding the permission of folder in which your pointing.

Go inside your project where your folder is located. Try go change the permission of your folder like this:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 yourfoldername
```

I hope after this you and everybody else who's struggling will not have anymore problems.

P.S. Becareful of giving 777 permission to your folders. I suggest you to dive in some info before doing that.