# I Think there is a Bug with Laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.4

i'm trying to send a email with Attachment File , It Work Perfectly when i'm using an externale link like :

```
public function build() 
{ return $this->view('email.test') ->attach("otherwebsite.com/file.pdf"); }
```

But when i try to send Files that stored on my Storage Folder like :

```
public function build() 
{ return $this->view('email.test') ->attach("mydomainename.com/storage/file.pdf"); }
```

, it Thrown an Eroor :

```
Swift_IoException in FileByteStream.php line 144: Unable to open file for reading
```

i had already generated a Storage:LINK , that allow to me to access to Storage Folder and i can access to it via url ( mydomainenname.com/storage/file.pdf ) ,

Please Help me What should i do ? it's been 3 days i'm trying to resolve this problem and nothing Found :/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531180/php-swift-mailer-problem

Comment: The linked answer should help. You need to pass the full `path` to the file, not the relative. Laravel has a helper function `storage_path('file.pdf')` that will help you in this instance.