# Laravel 5.2 email attatchment-pdf file in storage folder

Tags: php, email, laravel-5, attachment

I have a file in `storage/invoice/filename.pdf`

```
$data=[
 'billing_filepath'=>storage_path('/invoice/filename.pdf');,
 'invoice.pdf'];
```

I used laravel Mail function,
Email send success, but attachment was crashed. How can I fixed it.

```
$message->attachData($data['billing_filepath'], data['billing_file_name']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the PDF file is saved on your disk, use `attach()` instead of `attachData()`.

```
$message->attach($data['billing_filepath'],[
  'as' => data['billing_file_name'],
  'mime' => 'application/pdf'
]);
```

`attachData()` is used to send raw data which normally your program generate and you don't want to save on disk. `attachData()` accepts raw data bytes for the first argument **not** a file path.

Comment: I got an error message,
Swift_IoException in FileByteStream.php line 144: Unable to open file for reading [/var/www/vhosts/uneek_dev/uneek.sf.com.au/httpdocs/web/storage/invoice/order_8_invoice.pdf]

Comment: Check the permission of your storage and invoices directories (change it to 755 if not already). Try using `realpath()` instead of `storage_path()`, check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531180/php-swift-mailer-problem